# How to store current currency in session in REST API Magento 2.3?

Tags: magento2.3

> I have used the belove method to store current currency in session using Custom API but can not get current currency wise output in Default API in Magento 2.3

```
protected $_storeManager;

public function __construct(
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    )

{
 $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
}

$storeManager = $this->_storeManager;
if ($currency) {
    $storeManager->getStore()->setCurrentCurrencyCode($currency);
}
```